# Compiler errors: Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I'm trying to execute a compile Java file I'm getting this error:

> Could not find or load main class XYZ

The class exists in the bin folder.

```
<pre>
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Java\bin
C:\Java\bin>javac PhraseOmatic.java
C:\Java\bin>java PhraseOmatic
Error: Could not find or load main class PhraseOmatic
C:\Java\bin>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Java\lib
C:\java\bin>javac PhraseOmatic.java
C:\Java\bin>java PhraseOmatic
Error: Could not find or load main class PhraseOmatic
</pre>
```

[image]

Comment: do you use any package in your java file?

Comment: You should not have set the `CLASSPATH`, and you especially should not have set it to where you have -- despite what anyone else may have told you! If you unset the environment variable, the current directory becomes the default, and your session about will work as expected. But `don't` work inside `C:\Java\bin` for goodness sake! Create a directory elsewhere for your code, and just put `C:\Java\bin`  on your `PATH`.

Comment: Next go around, please show your error information as text, not as an image, since it is easier for us to read and doesn't get blocked by firewalls. You can easily capture all the text in a Windows Cmd box by right-clicking on the box, selecting "select all", and then enter. That copies all of the text to your system's clipboard. Then paste it in notepad, and voilà, you're all set and so are we.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill So I have to enter **pathclass** each and every time I begin afresh. Is there a possible solution.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry for the inconvenience. I've made changes now.

Comment: What's in that directory?  Could you do a `dir` and show the results?

Comment: @Makoto I've shared the prntscrn for the same. I guess it helps.

Comment: That's the `dir` for `C`. We need to see `C:/Java/bin`.

Comment: @Makoto Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your output your `CLASSPATH` is set to `C:\Java\lib` while you compile your classes in `C:\Java\bin`!

Note that the output of the compiler goes to the current directory (or the one specified by `-d`) and *not* on the classpath!

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have java in your environment variables you should do that.

For now, you can run "C:\Java\bin\javac PhraseOmatic.java" while you are in the directory where your java file is, in Command Prompt

C:\myfolder>C:\Java\bin\javac PhraseOmatic.java

Comment: Although this advice is good, it doesn't solve his problem, which is the bogus CLASSPATH setting.

Comment: That was not what was in the original, unedited post. Why was I downvoted for this?